# only fetching the needed data points from an odata endpoint

Tags: node.js, odata

I'm trying to query an Odata service, in order to filter and fetch the needed x and y data points in following data structure,

```
{
name: abc,
data: [{x:1, y:10}, {x:2, y:20}, {x:3, y:30}, {x:4, y:40}]
}
```

In an example of that I want to fetch a subset of above data points, where x are less than 3, and y can be any. The query results would ideally only have,

```
{data: [{x:1, y:10}, {x:2, y:20}]}
```

I have tried quite a few queries as following without luck..

```
GET scatter?$select=data&$filter=data/any(d:d/x lt 3)
GET scatter?$select=data&$filter=data/x lt 3
GET scatter?$select=data&$filter=x lt 3
```

Plus I'm currently using [node-odata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-odata), which does not have all query functions that are available at this stage. But it would be fine to use other Odata libraries, as long as they can solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not related to direct question of how to filter but, if "data" is a navigation property, shouldn't you use $expand instead of $select?

Comment: Hi Marvin, I'm afraid the "data" is not an expandable property. Shall I set it to be a navigation property that is expandable? I'm actually not very sure about this part, as I'm very new to Odata. All the property settings are done by the library automatically.. @MarvinSmit